# Different values on the function implementation

Tags: c++

I'm kind of new with programming and I have wired problem.
I tried to search and read about it, but without success.

I have main file and one class (on windows)

main:

```
 main()
 {
     LogOut x();
     x.WriteToDelayFile(1.2, 3);
 }
```

`LogOut` class:

```
 void LogOut::WriteToDelayFile(double simTime, int nodeNum)
 {
    string fileName = "Delay" + nodeNum;
    FILE* pFile = OpenFile(fileName);
    fputs ("something\n",pFile);
 }
```

I can't figure it out but when I call to `WriteToDelayFile(2, 3)` with values, I get garbage values **edit: (for example, on debug- nodeNum=321546 instead of nodeNum=3)** on the `LogOut::WriteToDelayFile(double simTime, int nodeNum)` implementation

Why does it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by garbae value? Please provide the end of your `WirteToDelayFile` function.

Comment: On which operating system and compiler? Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and **use the debugger**

Comment: You can't concatenate numbers with string literals like this `"Delay" + nodeNum;`, use a `stringstream` or `std::to_string`.

Comment: Don't trust the debugger blindly. Try printing the argument value if it makes no sense, beside the bad assumption about the concatenation. I've had this happen in VS a few times with /clr enabled.

Comment: -1, obviously not the actual code. `main()`?! `LogOut x();`?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolf you are a little bit wrong

```
string s = "hello"+3;
```

gives "lo" in s data

and

```
string si = string("hello")+3;
```

is incorrect you need to use stringstream instead

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello" << 3;
std::string s = ss.str();
```

Dudi Reuveni how can you tell that nodeNum has wrong data?

Comment: Can you print nodeNum on console and confirm it has wrong data?

Comment: o.k this is wired, I added "printf("%d",nodeNum);" and it showed me 3.. why?

Comment: It's only a guess but maybe you check nodeNum before you enter a method or debugger doesn't refresh value of nodeNum or you project is not build in debug mode.

Comment: you were write! I didn't build the project on debug mode (oops)!

Answer (score 2):

As user657267 pointed out in his comment, you may not concatenate a string literal and an int `string fileName = "Delay" + nodeNum;`. Here you are getting a pointer into the literal, that may even be out of range:

```
string s = "hello"+1; // leads to "ello" in s
```

The probably intended concatenation can be done using a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <assert>

void concat_check()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello" << 1;
    assert(ss.str() == "hello1");
}
```

Comment: o.k thank you very much for the correction! hmmm what about the actual value of "nodeNum" instead of 3 it gets 321546. thanks

Comment: The concatenation here isn't correct either. String will make no attempt at interpreting the integer as its string representation. It will in fact try to convert it to a single char, in which case 3 != '3'.
C++11 has std::to_string for this purpose or use a std::stringstream for more formatting options.

Comment: @Zoomulator absolutely, I tried to extrapolate from the VCL-class System::AnsiString, and I obviously failed. Thx.